# Laravel Paypal Payout. How to make it complete ? It returns json response

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have created single batch payout using their [documentation](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payouts/CreateSinglePayout.php).  so that I can send money to seller.

But I don't know what I should do after it. How can I show a payment form, where user can login in PayPal and pay the amount?

This is my code in controller function

```
 public function payViaPaypal(){
   
        $payouts = new \PayPal\Api\Payout();
        $senderBatchHeader = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader();
        $senderBatchHeader->setSenderBatchId(uniqid('invoice-1qaqw23wdwdwew').microtime('true'))
            ->setEmailSubject("You have a Payout!");

        $senderItem = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem();
        $senderItem->setRecipientType('Email')
            ->setNote('Thanks for your patronage!')
            ->setReceiver('sb-cwdzv2614448@business.example.com')
            ->setSenderItemId(uniqid().microtime('true'))
            ->setAmount(new \PayPal\Api\Currency('{
                        "value":"1.0",
                        "currency":"USD"
                    }'));

        $payouts->setSenderBatchHeader($senderBatchHeader)
            ->addItem($senderItem);



        $request = clone $payouts;
        $redirect_url = null;
        try {
            $output = $payouts->create(null, $this->api_context);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd('here',$this->errorDetails($e));
        }
//        dd("Created Single Synchronous Payout", "Payout", $output->getBatchHeader()->getPayoutBatchId(), $request, $output);
        $redirect_url = null;
        foreach($output->getLinks() as $link) {
            if($link->getRel() == 'self') {
                $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
                break;
            }
        }
        return $output;
}
```

when I hit route to access this code and I receive this json response.

```
{ "batch_header": { "payout_batch_id": "79CTFV2X5TS58", "batch_status": "PENDING", "sender_batch_header": { "sender_batch_id": "invoice-1qaqw23wdwdwew5f0f5003612091594839043.3978", "email_subject": "You have a Payout!" } }, "links": [ { "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts/79CTFV2X5TS58", "rel": "self", "method": "GET", "enctype": "application/json" } ] }
```

I am expecting that user will be taken to PayPal payment page where user will login and pay amount after that PayPal will inform me about the payment.

But I have tried to find the solution over internet but no example/solution I can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Payouts is for sending money from your account to another account. There is no form to show or log into. You are the API caller, and payments are automatically approved as coming from your account.

If you want a form for a user to approve paying from their account to some other account, use invoicing: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/invoicing/

Alternatively, maybe you don't need an invoice form but just a regular PayPal Checkout with a 'payee' recipient set: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/

Comment: After reading your answer, This example took me exactly where I wanted to go. 
https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreateThirdPartyPayment.html

Comment: That v1 SDK is no longer maintained, you should use https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK

Answer (score 0):

I was using wrong approach.

Solution is to create a payment object and add payee (who will receive payment as seller) email address in it.

There are two functions required.

1 to create payment object
2 to get payment details from paypal using API and then execute this payment so that amount can be transferred to receipeint account.

**3 Routes are required for following**

1. create payment object
2. get details payment object details (to see if customer has paid the amount using paypal checkout) and execute payment to send money (it is success url)
3. cancel url (when customer cancel to pay). It will redirect customer back to platform (website)

Here is full code example

**Routes**

```
create payment object
Route::get('/invoices/process-payment','Vendor\PayPalController@processPaymentInvoiceViaCheckout');

when payment object is created then get its details and execute payment to send money.
Route::get('/invoices/response-success','Vendor\PayPalController@paypalResponseSuccess');

when cancel to pay 
Route::get('/invoices/response-cancel','Vendor\PayPalController@paypalResponseCancel');
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Vendor;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payee;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter;

class PayPalController extends Controller

{
    private $api_context;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->api_context = new ApiContext(
            new OAuthTokenCredential(config('paypal.client_id'), config('paypal.secret'))
        );
        $this->api_context->setConfig(config('paypal.settings'));
    }
    public function processPaymentInvoiceViaCheckout(){
        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

        $item1 = new Item();
        $item1->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(1)
//            ->setSku("123123") // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
            ->setPrice(7.5);
        $item2 = new Item();
        $item2->setName('Granola bars')
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(5)
//            ->setSku("321321") // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
            ->setPrice(2);

        $itemList = new ItemList();
        $itemList->setItems(array($item1, $item2));
        $details = new Details();
        $details->setShipping(1.2)
            ->setTax(1.3)
            ->setSubtotal(17.50);
        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency("USD")
            ->setTotal(20)
            ->setDetails($details);
        $payee = new Payee();

        //this is the email id of the seller who will receive this amount

        $payee->setEmail("seller-paypal-businness-account-email@business.example.com");
        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($itemList)
            ->setDescription("Payment description")
            ->setPayee($payee)
            ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());
        $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(url('/invoices/response-success'))
            ->setCancelUrl(url('/invoices/response-cancel'));
        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent("sale")
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
            ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
        $request = clone $payment;
        try {
            //create payment object
            $createdPayment = $payment->create($this->api_context);
            //get payment details to get payer id so that payment can be executed and transferred to seller.
            $paymentDetails = Payment::get($createdPayment->getId(), $this->api_context);
            $execution = new PaymentExecution();
            $execution->setPayerId($paymentDetails->getPayer());
            $paymentResult = $paymentDetails->execute($execution,$this->api_context);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            //handle exception here
        }
        //Get redirect url
        //The API response provides the url that you must redirect the buyer to. Retrieve the url from the $payment->getApprovalLink() method
        $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

        return redirect($approvalUrl);
    }

    public function paypalResponseCancel(Request $request)
    {

        //normally you will just redirect back customer to platform
        return redirect('invoices')->with('error','You can cancelled payment');
    }

    public function paypalResponseSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        if (empty($request->query('paymentId')) || empty($request->query('PayerID')) || empty($request->query('token'))){
            //payment was unsuccessful
            //send failure response to customer
        }
        $payment = Payment::get($request->query('paymentId'), $this->api_context);
        $execution = new PaymentExecution();
        $execution->setPayerId($request->query('PayerID'));

        // Then we execute the payment.
        $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->api_context);


        dd($request->all(),$result);
       //payment is received,  send response to customer that payment is made.
    }
}
```

You can read this official [example](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/) as well

Comment: I am getting error when implementing this on line  return redirect($approvalUrl);

Comment: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in